# SSRS Compare Row of values in two diffrent textboxes.

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, compare, report

I am trying to take the values from one text box and compare if they are less than or greater than each other. 
One text box being "OngradeTrend" and the other being "OngradeTrendPrevious"
When I execute, it returns "0's" See Pictures Attached!

I have tried:
 `=IIF(ReportItems![OngradeTrend].Value < ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value, "DOWN", IIF(ReportItems![OngradeTrend].Value > ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value, "UP", 0))`

[Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdqSi.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH6oF.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may just be getting confused because you're specifying two strings, "down" and "up", and one number, 0. Try encasing the zero in quotation marks to make it a string:

```
=IIF(ReportItems![OngradeTrend].Value < ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value, "DOWN", IIF(ReportItems![OngradeTrend].Value > ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value, "UP", "0"))
```

You can also use the SWITCH statement, preferably with a default value in case your other options fail (like if one of your test fields are NULL). SWITCH doesn't have an "else" default value, but you can trick it with "true", which always evaluates to "true":

```
=SWITCH(
    ReportItems![OngradeTrend].Value < ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value, "DOWN",
    ReportItems![OngradeTrend].Value > ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value, "UP",
    true, "0")
```

Comment: Hmm, I would change the trend field to just show the value of the [OngradeTrendPrevious] value so you can make sure it has the values you're expecting. Is [OngradeTrendPrevious] a number? It seems like it should be [OngradePrevious] - without the "trend" - because you should be comparing the values. This might be comparing "down" to "down".

Comment: Refer to the pictures. "OngradeTrend" and "OngradeTrendPrevious" are just the titles of the text box. When it displays it is a row of data.

Comment: When I try to just put "=ReportItems![OngradeTrendPrevious].Value" I get blank spaces in return. Same way with "OngradeTrend"

Comment: Click one of those text boxes, click "Properties", and check the name of the textbox. I suspect that while the data stored in it might be [OngradeTrend], the textbox name is something like "TextBox55". If that's the case, you'll either need to rename the textbox or alter your formula to TextBox55.Value.

Comment: I changed the textbox name to "OngradeTrend"

Comment: Do the same for OngradeTrendPrevious and see if the function will run.